# Why does the losing tech graph require scrolling? (2016 Survey)

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2016

The "Winners" graph boasts increases of over 100%, while the largest "losers" decrease is only -62%. Why does the "Losers" graph require horizontal scrolling, until it reaches -30%?

[image: loser-tech]

Comment: Completed, though the survey has not been released yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Err, we made a mistake and this was released before it was ready.  It's been pulled and we're hoping to have it available next week for actual perusal.

Sorry about that!